# How to speed up slow SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

```
Table ideas: id, author_id, some_columns

Table ideas_tags: idea_id, tag_name

Table ideas_seen: idea_id, user_id

Table user: uid, ban, some_columns
```

I need to get 10 ideas which have tags from the list, whose author is not banned, and which not in ideas_seen for the current user.

Now my query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
ideas.*,  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IT_V.tag_name SEPARATOR '|||') AS tags 
FROM `ideas` 
LEFT JOIN ideas_tags IT 
ON ideas.id=IT.idea_id 
LEFT JOIN ideas_tags IT_V 
ON ideas.id=IT_V.idea_id 
LEFT JOIN ideas_seen IV 
ON ideas.id=IV.idea_id AND IV.user_id=145974517 
LEFT JOIN users ON users.uid=ideas.author_id 

WHERE author_id!=145974517 AND IV.id IS NULL AND ( (IT.tag_name = 'some_tag') OR (IT.tag_name = 'another_tag') OR (IT.tag_name IS NULL) ) AND active=1 AND deleted=0 AND (users.ban=0 OR users.ban IS NULL) 

GROUP BY ideas.id 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

It is the slowest query on the website and I don't know how to speed up it.

EXPLAIN:
[image: Explain query]

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ideas` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tutorial` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  `author_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `active` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `views` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `views_all` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `many_users` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `game_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=35983 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ideas_seen` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idea_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3694368 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ideas_tags` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idea_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tag_name` tinytext NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=86832 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `email` tinytext,
  `password_hash` tinytext,
  `restore_code` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `last_action` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `score` float NOT NULL,
  `date_register` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `posts_length` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `settings` text,
  `titles` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `filter` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `note` text NOT NULL,
  `ban` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mod_send` smallint(6) DEFAULT '0',
  `mod_get` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `fp_notified` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `skilled` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `show_only_skilled` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


ALTER TABLE `ideas`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD KEY `author_id` (`author_id`), ADD KEY `game_id` (`game_id`), ADD KEY `active` (`active`), ADD KEY `many_users` (`many_users`), ADD KEY `deleted` (`deleted`), ADD KEY `tutorial` (`tutorial`), ADD FULLTEXT KEY `idea_text` (`text`);

ALTER TABLE `ideas_seen`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD KEY `user_id` (`user_id`), ADD KEY `idea_id` (`idea_id`);

ALTER TABLE `ideas_tags`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD KEY `tag_name` (`tag_name`(255)), ADD KEY `idea_id` (`idea_id`);

ALTER TABLE `users`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`uid`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`(255)), ADD KEY `ban` (`ban`), ADD KEY `fp_notified` (`fp_notified`), ADD KEY `skilled` (`skilled`);


ALTER TABLE `ideas`
MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=35983;
ALTER TABLE `ideas_seen`
MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=3694368;
ALTER TABLE `ideas_tags`
MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=86832;

ALTER TABLE `ideas`
ADD CONSTRAINT `ideas_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`game_id`) REFERENCES `games` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION;

ALTER TABLE `ideas_seen`
ADD CONSTRAINT `ideas_seen_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`idea_id`) REFERENCES `ideas` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

ALTER TABLE `ideas_tags`
ADD CONSTRAINT `ideas_tags_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`idea_id`) REFERENCES `ideas` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Comment: You haven't shown us what your indexes are and what your numbers are like

Comment: Indexes on every column used in query.

Comment: What mean numbers?

Comment: which is insufficient information. Post your show create table

Comment: Do you get a different resultset if all the `LEFTs` are removed?  If so, I suggest that these two clauses are fighting each other:  `author_id!=145974517` and `IV.id IS NULL`.

Comment: Do you get the same resultset if you combine `IT` and `IT_V`?  I don't see the need for joining to that table twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Don't use `TINYTEXT`; change to `VARCHAR(255)` and get rid of the "prefixing" on indexes.  That is, change `INDEX email(255)` to `INDEX(email)`.
- Don't index 'flags', such indexes won't be used because they won't be useful.  Example: `deleted`
- Don't make one index the 'left' part of another.  Example `PRIMARY KEY(id)` vs `INDEX(id, ...)`.  In the case of `PRIMARY KEY`, keep it; toss the other as providing no extra benefit.
- I don't see the need to join to  `idea_tags` twice; see if you can avoid that.
- The query suffers from the "inflate-deflate" syndrome.  First it uses `JOINs` to inflate the number of rows, then it uses `GROUP BY` to get back to exactly the original rows (less some that got filtered out.)  In doing so, the bulky `ideas.*` is hauled around in temp table(s).
- `TEXT` (including `TINYTEXT`) prevents the more efficient use of `MEMORY` for tmp tables.

Let's walk through the elimination of the inflate-deflate.

First, let's structure the outer part:

```
SELECT ideas.*, ( ??? ) as tags
    FROM ideas
    WHERE ???
    ORDER BY ideas.id DESC
    LIMIT 10;
```

*Assuming* we can fill in `???`, we now have a path to a much faster evaluation.  This would require an index on `id`, which you have with `PRIMARY KEY(id)`.  With luck, (and without the `WHERE`), *only* 10 rows would need to be touched.  (In your version, the entire table must be gathered, grouped, sorted, and only then 10 delivered.)

Since all your `JOINs` are `LEFT JOINs`, we can provably say that the `WHERE` clauses that touch tables other than `ideas` will not filter out any rows.  that leaves

```
WHERE author_id!=145974517
  AND  active=1
  AND  deleted=0
```

For that, let's have (though I am not sure it will be used):

```
INDEX(active, deleted, author_id)
```

Back to `AS tags`...  Now strip down the query to get just the `tag_name` values to make that `GROUP_CONCAT` for a given `ideas.id`:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IT_V.tag_name SEPARATOR '|||') AS tags
    FROM       ideas_tags IT_V  ON ideas.id = IT_V.idea_id
      AND  (      IT.tag_name = 'some_tag'
              OR  IT.tag_name = 'another_tag'
              OR  IT.tag_name IS NULL
           )
```

(And here is where I get lost in why there were two joins to `idea_tags`.)  Meanwhile, I suggest that `SELECT` can be the subquery to get `tags`.

Hmmm.. what about

```
LEFT JOIN  users ON users.uid = ideas.author_id 
WHERE ( users.ban=0  OR  users.ban IS NULL )
```

That seems to do *no* filtering since it is `LEFT`.  It seems to provide *no* columns, since `users` is not mentioned elsewhere.  So, I have to  assume it is wasted code?

Ditto for

```
LEFT JOIN  ideas_seen IV    ON ideas.id = IV.idea_id
                 AND  IV.user_id=145974517
WHERE   IV.id IS NULL
```

So, it has boiled down to removing some indexes, adding one index, and rewriting the query as

```
SELECT  ideas.*, 
        ( SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IT_V.tag_name SEPARATOR '|||')
            FROM  ideas_tags IT_V
            WHERE  ideas.id = IT_V.idea_id
              AND  (   IT.tag_name = 'some_tag'
                   OR  IT.tag_name = 'another_tag'
                   OR  IT.tag_name IS NULL ) 
        ) as tags
    FROM  ideas
    WHERE  author_id!=145974517
      AND  active=1
      AND  deleted=0
    ORDER BY  ideas.id DESC
    LIMIT  10;
```

Probably, the `DISTINCT` is unnecessary.